# Stripe 3d secure payment using PaymentIntent

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to implement Stripe PaymentIntent. When I create the PaymentIntent object I pass it request_three_d_secure to payment_method_options but the created PaymentIntent is not requesting 3d secure payment on confirmation. Here is how I am creating the PaymentIntent object.

```
$paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
     'amount' => 1099,
     'currency' => 'usd',
     'customer' => 'cus_XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
     'payment_method_options' => '[card][request_three_d_secure][any]',
     'payment_method' => 'card_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
]);

$paymentIntent =  $stripe->paymentIntents->confirm(
    $paymentIntent->id,
    ['payment_method' => 'pm_card_visa']
);
```

Am I am creating the PaymentIntent object correctly? Has anyone else faced any issues related to this?

Answer (score 2):

In your `confirm` call you're replacing whatever the `card_xxx` is with another test payment method that is "not enrolled". See [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#three-ds-cards) for details of the manual 3D Secure support for test cards. There are also SCA test cards here.

For this case, you likely want to attach `pm_card_threeDSecureOptional` instead, then manual 3DS requests should work like you expect.